# Изучение сортировок

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка

В чем заключается смысл изучения сортировок, если есть к примеру стандартные функции в языках программирования для сортировки массивов? Конечно, я не против изучения, просто интересно.

P.S. Я читал, что функция sort на C++ к примеру определяет размерность массива и сама решает какой вид сортировки использовать за O(n^2) к примеру на малых входных данных или за O(n*logn) на больших

Comment: В развитии алгоритмического мышления.

Comment: В том, что для разных входных данных можно применять разные сортировки. В некоторых случаях, пузырьковая сортировка может оказаться куда быстрее quick sort (к примеру, если данных - несколько десятков мегабайт, памяти в обрез, а данные почти отсортированы (2-3 элемента не на своих местах).

Comment: Например, чтобы понимать, что делает ваша стандартная сортировка, и какой может быть наихудший случай.

Comment: >Конечно, я не против изучения

вот спасибо так спасибо. А то уж мы было испугались

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Знаешь ли ты, что такое стабильные сортировки? Когда отсутствие стабильности может испортить тебе жизнь? Как реализована сортировка в твоей библиотечной функции? Обладает ли она свойством стабильности?
Знаешь ли ты, как оценить, насколько быстро отсортируются твои данные?
Знаешь ли ты, что сортировать числа или короткие строки можно сильно быстрей, если использовать нужный алгоритм сортировки?
Знаешь ли ты, как параллелить сортировки на несколько потоков и какую мощность можно из этого извлечь? Умеет ли твоя библиотечная функция выполнять сортировку в несколько потоков?

Это лишь пример вопросов, на которые стоит уметь отвечать. А для этого нужно понимать, как устроены различные алгоритмы сортировок. Ну и вообще, это та часть знаний по алгоритмам, которая достаточно базовая и даёт множество необходимых для любого программиста понятий и знаний.

UPD: Я думаю, эта [статья](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) поможет вам найти ответ на все интересующие вопросы

Comment: А что такое стабильность сортировки? ^^

Comment: ... и чтобы понимать, что такое стабильная сортировка :-P

Comment: @VladD, поясните пожалуйста, в двух словах :)

Comment: смотрите UPD

Answer (score 1):

Эффективность алгоритма сортировки в конкретном случае зависит от специфики данных. Знание принципа работы поможет выбрать более подходящую сортировку для конкретной задачи, пусть даже и стандартную из языка программирования.